# Jinja2 number format

Tags: python, jinja2

I've been looking a lot before raise this question here.
So this is what I'm doing:
I have the following json in a dictionary which I'm reading in Jinja2.
However the numbers are not well formated.
In the Key ITSA4
COTACAO : 1015.0
I need that display 10,15

In the key OIBR3
COTACAO: 119.0
I need that display 1,19.

Below you can see my dictorinary.

```
'ITSA4': {'Cotação': 1015.0, 
'P/L': 966.0, 
'P/VP': 164.0, 
'PSR': 16743.0, 
'Div.Yield': '8,57%', 
'P/Ativo': 1327.0, 
'P/Cap.Giro': 2173, 
'P/EBIT': 32961.0, 
'P/Ativ Circ.Liq': -2904, 
'EV/EBIT': 33354.0, 
'EV/EBITDA': 8999.0, 
'Mrg Ebit': '5,08%',
'Mrg. Líq.': '178,72%',
'Liq. Corr.': 258,
'ROIC': '0,43%', 
'ROE': '17,01%', 
'Liq.2meses': '312.166.00000', 
'Patrim. Líq': '51.962.000.00000', 
'Dív.Brut/ Patrim.': 9.0, 
'Cresc. Rec.5a': '2,20%'
}

'OIBR3': {'Cotação': 119.0, 
'P/L': 966.0, 
'P/VP': 164.0, 
'PSR': 16743.0, 
'Div.Yield': '8,57%', 
'P/Ativo': 1327.0, 
'P/Cap.Giro': 2173, 
'P/EBIT': 32961.0, 
'P/Ativ Circ.Liq': -2904, 
'EV/EBIT': 33354.0, 
'EV/EBITDA': 8999.0, 
'Mrg Ebit': '5,08%',
'Mrg. Líq.': '178,72%',
'Liq. Corr.': 258,
'ROIC': '0,43%', 
'ROE': '17,01%', 
'Liq.2meses': '312.166.00000', 
'Patrim. Líq': '51.962.000.00000', 
'Dív.Brut/ Patrim.': 9.0, 
'Cresc. Rec.5a': '2,20%'
}
```

This was the closest I've got from my plan.

```
{{ '{:.0f}'.format(value.Cotação) }}
```

But the output was 1015 and not 10,15 as I expected.

Any idea?

Comment: This doesn’t seem like a formatting issue. Or is there a locale in which the value 1050.0 is commonly written as 10,50? (The closest I could find was the Indian numbering system, which does something similar for multiples of 100000).

Comment: This is reading from a Json file and appending to the dictionary, maybe I can try to append to the dictionary converted already, do you have any idea?

Comment: I still don’t understand *why* you think that 1050 should be displayed as 10,50. The two are different values in Portuguese: 10,50 is 1050 / 100. So if you want that value I guess you need to first divide it by 100. And in American English, using the comma as a thousands separator, you’d write “1,050”, not “10,50” (and even here it’s convention to only use thousands separators for values ≥ 10,000, ie. you’d write 9999 but 10,001).

Comment: This is because I know the value is 10,50 and not 1050. That's why I want.

Comment: I managed to fix it from pandas which is the place where the data was coming from.
I had to include decimal=',', thousands='.'
pd.read_html(response.text, decimal=',', thousands='.')